# What's the most popular compiler, and what's so bad about MSVS?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, dev-c++

I've been using MS Visual Studio for a lot of projects, but I notice a lot of people here like to complain about Microsoft and Visual Studio.

So I'm wondering, what does everyone use?  Dev-C++? mingw?

What is popular? Also, what is bad about MSVS? What is "better" about the others?

Thanks!

--RKL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing compilers is often an exercise fraught with peril. Here is but a sampling of the variables you would have to normalize for:

- compiler flags
- compiler-specific preferences for idiomatic code
- differences between processors
- enabling/disabling of processor extensions
- differences in assumptions that can safely be made about code
- compiler extensions in use

Qualitatively speaking, MSVC is a serviceable compiler. There's not too much reason to complain about it, other than everyone's usual gripe of "I wish things were faster".

Comment: Also, I'm a little puzzled by this question and some of the answers. The OP seems to be talking about compilers (at least, he uses that word), but then the question and some of the answers are talking about IDEs, which are different than compilers.